# why its printing only 6 fields and not 7 python

Tags: python

How can I get the 7th record by using the below code?

```
from pprint import pprint
def date_op(total_input_list):
    total_pages=36
    list=[]
    for xy in total_input_list:
        for i in range(1,len(xy)):
            Start_page=xy[i]["start_page"]
            End_page=xy[i+1]["start_page"]-1
            Date = xy[i]["date"]
            list.append(Date)
            date=set(list)
            d1 = [{i: {"start_page": Start_page, "end_page": End_page,"date":date}}]
            print(d1)

total_input_list=[{1:{"start_page":1,"end_page":None,"date":"10/12/2015"},
              2:{"start_page":4,"end_page":None,"date":"12/12/2015"},
              3:{"start_page":8,"end_page":None,"date":"22/1/2016"},
              4:{"start_page":15,"end_page":None,"date":"22/1/2016"},
              5:{"start_page":22,"end_page":None,"date":"22/1/2016"},
              6:{"start_page":24,"end_page":None,"date":"20/12/2016"},
              7:{"start_page":28,"end_page":None,"date":"26/2/2017"}}]
date_op(total_input_list)
```

I'm seeing this output

```
[{1: {'date': {'10/12/2015'}, 'end_page': 3, 'start_page': 1}}]
[{2: {'date': {'10/12/2015', '12/12/2015'}, 'end_page': 7, 'start_page': 4}}]
[{3: {'date': {'22/1/2016', '10/12/2015', '12/12/2015'}, 'end_page': 14, 'start_page': 8}}]
[{4: {'date': {'22/1/2016', '10/12/2015', '12/12/2015'}, 'end_page': 21, 'start_page': 15}}]
[{5: {'date': {'22/1/2016', '10/12/2015', '12/12/2015'}, 'end_page': 23, 'start_page': 22}}]
[{6: {'date': {'22/1/2016', '10/12/2015', '12/12/2015', '20/12/2016'}, 'end_page': 27, 'start_page': 24}}]
```

Comment: range start from 1 so you have loss first item， should be 0

Comment: already tried to changed it to 0 showing keyerror.

Comment: why used i as iter index ， you can used ’enumerate‘ build in function

Comment: probably you should change all `i` in for to `i-1` to don't missing the first element

Comment: The `KeyError` is because you have no dictionary with key 0. Also, why do you have a list of one-item dicts, when all of them are different? If you want to iterate from 1 to 7 in your current model, you want `range(1, len(xy) + 1)`.

Comment: You could create an equivalent example with far less code and data. See how to create a [mcve]. Creating the example might help you understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because your iterator stops before len(xy)

```
def date_op(total_input_list):
total_pages=36
list=[]
for xy in total_input_list:
    for i in range(1,len(xy)+1):
        Start_page=xy[i]["start_page"]
        if(i<len(xy)):
            End_page=xy[i+1]["start_page"]-1
        Date = xy[i]["date"]
        list.append(Date)
        date=set(list)
        d1 = [{i: {"start_page": Start_page, "end_page": End_page,"date":date}}]
        print(d1)

total_input_list=[{1:{"start_page":1,"end_page":None,"date":"10/12/2015"},
          2:{"start_page":4,"end_page":None,"date":"12/12/2015"},
          3:{"start_page":8,"end_page":None,"date":"22/1/2016"},
          4:{"start_page":15,"end_page":None,"date":"22/1/2016"},
          5:{"start_page":22,"end_page":None,"date":"22/1/2016"},
          6:{"start_page":24,"end_page":None,"date":"20/12/2016"},
          7:{"start_page":28,"end_page":None,"date":"26/2/2017"}}]
date_op(total_input_list)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it has out of range error here `End_page=xy[i+1]["start_page"]-1`

Comment: date_op(total_input_list)
  File "C:/Users/karthik/doe.py", line 8, in date_op
    End_page=xy[i+1]["start_page"]-1
KeyError: 8

Comment: didn't get you @malugina

Comment: Yes. because looking forward add if(i<len(xy)) or another filter before line End_page=xy[i+1]["start_page"]-1

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a classical [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error).

[image]

7 timestamps define 6 durations.

To output the first line:

```
[{1: {'date': {'10/12/2015'}, 'end_page': 3, 'start_page': 1}}]
```

You need information from the first and second values of your dict.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're getting a value from the next field, you have to set the next value from position 7 to null, I'm assuming that the end_page on the last part will be null, otherwise all you have to do is change the except part.

This solves the issue:

```
for i in range(1,len(xy)+1):
    Start_page=xy[i]["start_page"]
    try: 
      End_page=xy[i+1]["start_page"]-1 #from 1 to 6, the value comes from here
    except:
      End_page=None # when on field 7, value will come from here
    Date = xy[i]["date"]
    list.append(Date)
    date=set(list)
    d1 = [{i: {"start_page": Start_page, "end_page": End_page,"date":date}}]
    print(d1)
```